# Using a function to get the ID of an element with getElementById()

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, onclick, getelementbyid

GET_COOKIE('CURRENT_IM') will return a number saved in the CURRENT_IM cookie. How can I get this to work?

This is in a onClick Attribute

```
document.getElementById('IM_INNER_'+GET_COOKIE('CURRENT_IM')).style.display='none';
```

Comment: Is the onclick attribute single-quoted or double-quoted?

Comment: double quote, it says document.getElementById("IM_INNER_" + GET_COOKIE("CURRENT_IM")) is null

Comment: Can you upload some source code in a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Can you *temporarily* add an alert('IM_INNER_'+GET_COOKIE('CURRENT_IM')); on the previous line and see if it is what you expect it to be, and that that id actually exists with the correct case.

Comment: @Shane: Then double-check an element with that ID really exists

Comment: @Shane: that's not double-quoted. **This** would be: `<a onclick="document.getElementById('IM_INNER'+...)..." />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is not working?

My immediate thought for debugging would be to set a variable.  Also, calling the `toString()`  on the integer return value may help.

```
  var id = 'IM_INNER_'+GET_COOKIE('CURRENT_IM').toString();
  alert(id);  //this will tell you what the id is.  you can view the source to see if it's correct
  document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
```

Comment: GET_COOKIE is returning nothing?

Comment: That means that the GET_COOKIE function is broken and is returning a null value.

Comment: Can you even link a function with a return inside a getElementById?

Comment: Yes, but if an element with the id is not in the current DOM then it won't work.

Comment: my GET_COOKIE() function was broken.